# BASH - psql: warning: extra command-line argument ignored

Tags: postgresql, bash

For the given BASH script, it is making use of PSQL to establish a database connection and make calls to the database. When running the script, it is raising the error: `psql: warning: extra command-line argument [some value] ignored`.

```
LINE 1: INSERT
              ^
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "INTO" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "teams" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "(name)" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "VALUES" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "('Argentina')," ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "('Switzerland')" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "ON" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "CONFLICT" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "(name)" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "DO" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "NOTHING;" ignored
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: INSERT
```

Particularly, it is raising that error for each word in the string assigned to `DB_INSERT_CALL`. When `DB_INSERT_CALL` is removed and the string formerly assigned to it is placed with in the subshell as `($PSQL "INSERT INTO...")` then the data is inserted into the database. Why does the parameter expansion of `$DB_INSERT_CALL` with respect to `($PSQL $DB_INSERT_CALL)` raise the aforementioned error?

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "test" ]]
then
  PSQL="psql --username=postgres --dbname=worldcuptest -t --no-align -c"
else
  PSQL="psql --username=freecodecamp --dbname=worldcup -t --no-align -c"
fi

# Do not change code above this line. Use the PSQL variable above to query your database.

cat 'games.csv' | while IFS="," read YEAR ROUND WINNER OPPONENT WINNER_GOALS OPPONENT_GOALS
do
  if [[ $YEAR != 'year' ]]
  then
    DB_INSERT_CALL="INSERT INTO teams (name) VALUES ('$WINNER'), ('$OPPONENT') ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING;"
    DB_INSERT_RESULT=$($PSQL $DB_INSERT_CALL)
  fi
done
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). You can't dynamically construct arbitrary argument lists into strings -- working beyond the trivially simple cases requires that your shell variables be _arrays_.

Comment: That is to say: `psql_args=( psql --username=postgres --dbname=worldcuptest -t --no-align -c )`, then `db_insert_result=( "${psql_args[@]}" "$db_insert_call" )` (note the use of lower-case variable names; all-caps names are used for variables special to the shell itself, lowercase names are reserved for application use -- see that standardized in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Comment: (...while that standard explicitly applies to environment variables, regular shell variables share the same namespace conventions since setting a shell variable implicitly overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable).

Comment: Two last notes. 1: Consider `while... done <games.csv` instead of `cat games.csv | while...done` to avoid the bugs described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). 2: Be sure to sanitize your variables to avoid shell injection -- someone who can put arbitrary data in your CSV file could also run arbitrary SQL commands. (It'd be _safer_ to switch away from bash to a language with database bindings that support bound variables, so you wouldn't need to rely on sanitization for safety).